# How to use Twitter Ads Api EndPoint in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, ads-api

Can anyone help me how to create request to Twitter ads api? I have try to run example in this page [GET accounts](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/campaign-management/api-reference/accounts.html), i run that example URL to my browser but it give error "This page can't be reached". I want try to create this request without sdk, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because you need to authenticate your request, there are multiple ways of doing so.

- [Basic Auth](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/basic-auth)
- [OAuth](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/using-oauth)

Use an application like Postman to post your requests because it provides easy way to configure authentication as well, or you can try curl.

Here is one such example, [build authorization header](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request)

```
Building the header string
To build the header string, imagine writing to a string named DST.

Append the string “OAuth ” (including the space at the end) to DST.
For each key/value pair of the 7 parameters listed above:
Percent encode the key and append it to DST.
Append the equals character ‘=’ to DST.
Append a double quote ‘”’ to DST.
Percent encode the value and append it to DST.
Append a double quote ‘”’ to DST.
If there are key/value pairs remaining, append a comma ‘,’ and a space ‘ ‘ to DST.
Pay particular attention to the percent encoding of the values when building 
this string. For example, the oauth_signature value of 
tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk/jLY= must be encoded as tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D.

OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog", 
oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg", 
oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1318622958", 
oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", 
oauth_version="1.0"
```

Comment: thanks for answer it, i will try it soon.
then it really different with facebook then, at facebook i can build single url with access_token on it, but can i do this with twitter? @MithunS

Comment: Using access tokens with twitter is possible. In this case, you would generate an access token and a secret for using it from an application. 
There are a couple of things to keep in mind though.

`Your application only needs to make requests on behalf of a single user
You wish to test API functionality from a single account only.
`

In short, with twitter access tokens are more for apps than for users.